# Why is Jekyll not working at all with Ruby 3.1?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I executed using Ruby 3.1:

```
gem install jekyll
```

Then I executed:

```
jekyll -v
```

And I got this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- sass-embedded (LoadError)
```

I tried to update ruby 3.1.2 to ruby-3.2.0-preview1, but I got more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed sass-embedded:

```
gem install sass-embedded
```

It seems to be working fine now.